# How can I code my web app so that it knows what web server it's on?

Tags: asp.net, load-balancing, web-farm

My company has an ASP.NET web app that runs on a web farm that's load balanced by Enterprise Foundry ServerIron XL 8 hardware. For debugging purposes, we've got a page that just reports what server it's running on. Currently, we manually copy a different version of this page to each server, and hardcode the name of that server (e.g. www1, www2, or www3).  What I'd like instead is to find a way for the app to determine this information itself, so we don't have to do this manual step, outside of the code itself, but I can't find any way to accomplish this.

So the question is: how can an ASP.NET app be made aware of where it's actually running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via IIS itself.

Find the web application. In the app's main config page (features view), under `IIS` section you'd find `HTTP Response Headers`. This feature enables you to add/remove headers which need to be sent along with every response of that application.

[image]

However, you'd need tools like fiddler to be able to inspect such data.

Another option is a custom server control or user control, placed anywhere within a page which will output that information during it Render phase (as html comment). You can get using [System.Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

```
var mc_name = System.Environment.MachineName;
```

Comment: I opted to use the `MachineName` code and a simple table to map machine names to the public facing subdomain (i.e. www1 or www2).  Thanks!